# how to delete group from expandable list view

Tags: android, expandablelistview

I am trying to get the primary key "_id" from the selected group using code

groupPositionID is a global variable initialized like this
and IngredientListGroup_cursor is a group cursor which fetches the group data for expanable list view.

```
String groupPositionID=null;
Cursor IngredientListGroup_cursor;
```

in the oncreate code:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
IngredientListGroup_cursor=helper.GetIngredientsList();
}

ExpandableIngredietnsList.setOnGroupClickListener(new OnGroupClickListener(){

                @Override
                public boolean onGroupClick(
                        ExpandableListView paramExpandableListView,
                        View paramView, int paramInt, long paramLong) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    groupPositionID=IngredientListGroup_cursor.getString(0);

                    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),groupPositionID ,Toast.LENGTH_LONG);       
                    toast.show();
                    return false;
                }

            });
```

this is my SQLhelper function for deleting the selected group from database.

```
public Cursor GetIngredientsList(){

    return(getReadableDatabase().rawQuery("SELECT _id,Ingredient_name FROM tblIngredients",null));

}

public Cursor DeleteIngredientsList_Item(String index){
        String[] args={index};
        return(getReadableDatabase().rawQuery("DELETE FROM tblIngredients WHERE _id=?",args));

}
```

The problem I am facing is tha although i am getting the id for the selected group from cursor (i m able to see that as toast) but then, why i am not able to delete that from context menu.

on selecting delete from context menu the following code should execute properly

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem IngredientItem){
    if(IngredientItem.getItemId()==R.id.addIngredient){
        Intent i= new Intent(Ingredients_List.this,Ingredients_Add.class);
        startActivity(i);
        return(true);
    }
    else if (IngredientItem.getItemId()==R.id.deleteIngredient) {

        if(groupPositionID!=null){
              helper.DeleteIngredientsList_Item(groupPositionID);
              return(true);
            }
            else{
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Select The Ingredient You want to delete", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
            }
    }
    return (super.onOptionsItemSelected(IngredientItem));

}
```

I am getting the selected primary key id value from "groupPositionID" variable here.. accurate value is transferred to database raw query also... still not getting what i am expecting

Plz help ASAP I am new to both android and java

sdk information(although not required)

```
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" 
android:minSdkVersion="8"
```

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
public void DeleteIngredientsList_Item(long index){

    String[] args = new String[]{Long.toString(index)};
    Log.v("I am in", "SQLHelper");
    getWritableDatabase().execSQL("DELETE FROM tblIngredients WHERE _id=?",args);

}
```

i modified this delete code in mysql helper

my function was earlier returning cursor thats why it was not working ... meanz in actual query was not getting executed...

rest was ok.. :)